# Get all item-Ids from a Collection

Tags: collection, cms-block, getmodel

I found out how to get the first item from a collection:

```
$pageId = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
          ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', 'your name in the pages')
          ->getFirstItem()
          ->getId();
```

But now I have 3 IDs with the same name but different store views.
How can I get these item-Ids?
When I write that statement above without "getFirstItem()" and/or without "getId()" then Magento throws me an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tipo,as you  want using `getFirstItem`(),it `only given 1 item,`you need to `remove this function` and  add `getAllIds`() function  on this collection.

**Full code:**

```
$pageIds = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
          ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', 'your name in the pages')
          //->getFirstItem()
          ->getAllIds();)
```

getAllIds() give all ids in  an array.

Comment: welcome ...:)....

Answer (score 1):

Try `getAllIds($limit = null, $offset = null)`

That is a method for a collection object. So, once you get your collection, you would do something like this:

```
$collection->getAllIds();
```

The $limit and $offset arguments are optional provide you with "paging" capabilities. E.g.

```
$collection->getAllIds(100,2500); // gets you 100 ids, starting from the 2500th of the collection (2500 - 2599)
```

Comment: Please add a little bit more of information and a complete example code snippet so beginners will understand your solution.

Comment: I guess that's why Amit got the checkmark even though he just copied my answer an hour later. Oh well.